# Codeigniter MySQL select max using varchar type value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, max

I want to select max auto_no from the following varchar type column in my codeigniter model

```
+------------+
|  auto_no   |
+------------+
| 2020-00821 |
| 2020-00822 |
| 2020-00823 |
| 2020-00824 |
| 2020-00825 |
+------------+
```

In this example that the value is 825. I tried following option

```
public function generate_auto_no($count = 1, $start = 00000, $digits = 5)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('letter_letter');
        $this->db->select("MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(auto_no, '-', -1) AS UNSIGNED)) AS auto_no", FALSE);        
        $count = ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->row()->auto_no + 1 : 0;
        $result = array();
        for ($n = $start; $n <= $start + $count; $n++) {
            $result[] = str_pad($n, $digits, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        }
        return date("Y").'-' . end($result);
    }
```

But didn't get the expected value. Can anyone help ?

Comment: I would be sorely tempted to revise the schema, to store year? and no? separately

Comment: Use the query `SELECT CAST(MAX(SUBSTRING(auto_no, -5)) AS UNSIGNED) AS max_no FROM auto_table` [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/892a84/6)

Comment: @ Madan. Its ok. But the function should be included into $this->db->..............

Comment: You can do that :) `$this->db->select(..., false)`. Use `false` as second paramter to accept raw SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin you can just select the max string:

```php
$this->db->select_max("auto_no");
$query = $this->db->get('letter_letter');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $last_auto_no = $query->row()->auto_no;
    $no = intval(explode('-', $last_auto_no)[1]) + 1;
    $auto_no = date("Y").'-' . str_pad($no, $digits, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
} else {
    $auto_no = (date("Y").'-' . str_pad(0, $digits, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT));
}
return $auto_no
```

Comment: @ TsaiKoga. But it didn't include the table name. Assume table as letter_letter

Comment: @MCITTrends then use `get(table_name)`

Comment: @  TsaiKoga. But it reruns the min value as 2020-00001. All function as edited. Pls. see on edit

Comment: @MCITTrends I think you can just take the max `auto_no` and increase it like my post.

Comment: @ TsaiKoga. I think that is closed to the expected output. But outs the error, Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: models/Letter_model.php

Line Number: 346

Comment: @ TsaiKoga. Line No 346 is $no = intval(explode('-', $last_auto_no)[1]) + 1; in your query

Comment: @MCITTrends It seems the `$last_auto_no` has no `-`; can u `var_dump( $query->row()->auto_no;)` to see what it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206637/discussion-between-mcit-trends-and-tsaikoga).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using custom query :

```
$this->db->query(" SELECT MAX( CAST( SUBSTR(auto_no,INSTR(auto_no,'-')+1,LENGTH(auto_no)) AS SIGNED) ) FROM tab ");
```

including well-known string operators of MySQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

The naximum value can be retrieved by using `MAX()` for the `varchar` values and then extracting the number of the last 5 chars:

```
select right(max(in_num), 5) + 0
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cSx9F4KTNvMgzFiMRNPbna/0).
Result:

```
825
```

Comment: @ forpas. Can you add your suggestion into $this->db->select_max()

Comment: @ forpas. No that is not. In Codeigniter, should be used $this->db->select_max in the left